# Load JSON, YAML, and XML files in a Singleton Pattern

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a ConfigLoader that loads YAML, XML, and JSON files in a singleton method, i just got started but got stuck in terms of where else to go, and how to load a YAML file

heres what I have so far, i need some insights on how to translate this into a singleton pattern, and some insights on how to load a YAML file

```
let getXMLFile = function(path, callback) {
    //create new object
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //open the object and specify verb and file path
    request.open("GET", path);
    //set header of httprequest
    request.setrequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");

    //set event listener
    request.onReadystatechange= function(){
        //check to see ready state and event status
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
            callback(request.responseXML);
        }      
    };
    request.send();
};

getXMLFile("fileName.xml", function(xml){
    console.log(xml);
});

"use strict";
//Loading Json File with fetch
//using URL and http
//use request object to define key
let myRequest = new Request("./data_class.json")
//pass request object
fetch(myRequest).then(function(resp){
    //return response but act on it with Json method
    //convert text to json file
    return resp.json();
})
//handle JSON data
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml

Comment: Well for a Singleton you'll need a Class (eg.: ConfigLoader). This class can have methods like 'loadXML', 'loadYAML', ... but I dont see why you should use a singleton here, because you could simply make the methods static instead. You want to use a singleton when you want to use a single instance in multiple scopes. Like a shopping-cart for example. But simple file parsing. Maybe its better if you tell what you actually try to accomplish